# Proof: infimum and supremum of family of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, supremum-and-infimum

I am really struggling with how to write down a proper proof (in general but particularly with this problem), the exact exercise states:

Let $X$ be a set and $\mathcal{P}(X)$ its powerset. Let $A \neq \emptyset$ be a subset of $\mathcal{P}(X)$. Show that $\sup A$ equals the union of $A$ and $\inf A$ the intersection of $A$.

Edit: While $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is ordered by $\subseteq$.

---

It makes intuitive sense to me. Since any set in $A$ is logically a subset of the union of all sets in $A$. And the intersection of $A$ would be a set that is a subset of all other sets in $A$: worst-case the empty set.

My only problem is how to write this down in the form of an acceptable proof.

Apologies for the maybe trivial question, but I feel like I never learned how to write a proper proof.

Comment: How are you defining $\sup A$ and $\inf A$ for an arbitrary set $A$?

Comment: I imagine this is the sup and inf viewing $\mathcal{P}(X)$ ordered by $\subseteq$, but it would be good to clarify. So sup(A) is the $\subseteq$-least subset of $X$ which contains all elements of $A$ as a subset, and similarly for inf.

Comment: @FrancisAdams

Yes, sorry, ordered by $\subseteq$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, under inclusion, every non-empty $A\in\mathcal{P}(X)$ has both an upper bound and a lower bound.  This is because 
$$u=\bigcup_{s\in A}s$$
is greater than or equal to every $s\in A$ (since $s\subseteq u$ for all $s\in A$ by the definition of $u$), and also
$$l=\bigcap_{s\in A}s$$
is less than or equal to every $s\in A$ (since $s\supseteq l$ for all $s\in A$ by the definition of $l$).  We will now show that $u$ and $l$ are the least upper bound and the greatest lower bound of $A$.

Suppose that $u'$ and $l'$ are an arbitrary upper bound and an arbitrary lower bound of $A$.  Then $s\subseteq u'$ and $s\supseteq l'$ for every $s\in A$.  Therefore,
$$u=\bigcup_{s\in A}s\subseteq u'$$
and 
$$l=\bigcap_{s\in A}s\supseteq l'.$$
The claim follows.